# NFS Volumes in Docker/Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, nfs, boot2docker, docker-compose

I'm using boot2mac and docker-compose. I want to be able to configure this to mount my volume via NFS. This is my configuration:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
db:
    image: postgres
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define an nfs volume in a compose file do as described in this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-how-to-use-nfs-volumes/23255/2):

```
volumes:
  name:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=192.168.1.1,rw
      device: ":/path/to/dir"
```

This is supported since at least composefile version 2